# rendering component with previous url path React JS without using useHistory

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to build dynamic breadcrumbs using Material UI React JS. I want to access the previous url path in the BrowserStack and using that create links in the breadcrumbs.

Current react version is 6.2, useHistory() has been deprecated.

Tried useNavigate(-1) but not able to retrieve path with using it.

Is there any solution to it?

Tried react-router-dom different hook props and props but was not able to achieve it with them.
The only possible option I see is accessing it from browser stack

Comment: Have you tried using the history library?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass down state using the  component, in this case a pathname:

```
<Link to={{pathname: '/nextpath', state: { prevPath: location.pathname }}}>Example Link</Link>
```

You can then access prevPath from this.props.location.state in the next component